# Как правильно подсчитать количество минут поверх заданного тарифа - pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подсчитать правильно количество минут поверх заданного тарифа и записать результат в один столбец?

Задача следующая : есть таблица с данными по количеству клиентов в телеком компании, а также их тарифами и количеством минут, которые операторы тратили за конкретный месяц. Необходимо просчитать количество исходящих минут по внутренним звонкам и сравнить, был ли превышен лимит у того или иного клиента. У меня сложность встала в том, что я логически понимаю как подсчитать всё это, но вот как выстроить условия для трех разных тарифов и записать всю в один столбец - тупняк полный. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Таблица, в которую планирую добавлять данные по следующим критериям

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример моего кода:

```
internal_over_limit = ((df_revenue_month['direction']=='out') &
                       (df_revenue_month['internal']==True) &
                       (df_revenue_month['tariff_plan']=='C') &
                       (df_revenue_month['total_minutes']>0))

df_revenue_month.loc[internal_over_limit, 'minutes_internal_over_limit'] = df_revenue_month['total_minutes'] - 0    
df_revenue_month['minutes_internal_over_limit'] = df_revenue_month['minutes_internal_over_limit'].fillna(0)    
df_revenue_month.head(5)
```

Глобально - он выполняет мою цель, но лишь частично. У каждого тарифного плана свой лимит, который нужно отсчитывать и выводить в новый столбец данные ТОЛЬКО поверх лимита. А - 2000, B - 500, С - 0.

Направьте, пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описание вопроса неполное - нет воспроизводимого фрагмента исходных данных и отсутствует образец ожидаемого результата, который должен получаться после обработки данных. Сделал, как понял. Может, угадал, а может, и нет.
По сути решения. Сначала нужно отфильтровать фрейм `df = df[df.direction.eq('out') & df.internal]`. Далее группируем по id и plan и применяем transform(sum), суммируя все минуты по каждой группе. После чего отнимаем Series c плановыми минутами, полученный путем замены букв плана на плановые лимиты, заданные в словаре limits. Результат обрабатываем методом mask, заменяя отрицательные числа на 0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [123] * 3 + [456] * 3, 'plan': ['B'] * 3 + ['A'] * 3, 'direction': ['in', 'out'] * 3, 'internal': [False, True] * 3, 'minutes': [200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 3000]})
limits = {'A': 2000, 'B': 500, 'C': 0}
print(df)
df = df[df.direction.eq('out') & df.internal]
df['over'] = (df.groupby(['id', 'plan']).minutes.transform(sum) - df.plan.replace(limits)).mask(lambda x: x < 0, 0)
print(df)
```

```
    id plan direction  internal  minutes
0  123    B        in     False      200
1  123    B       out      True      300
2  123    B        in     False      400
3  456    A       out      True      100
4  456    A        in     False      200
5  456    A       out      True     3000
    id plan direction  internal  minutes  over
1  123    B       out      True      300     0
3  456    A       out      True      100  1100
5  456    A       out      True     3000  1100
```

Comment: Алексей, добрый день!

Comment: Спасибо за идею и пример решения! В данном случае это решение не совсем подходит для ситуации, так как в конечном счете мы должны отфильтровать количество минут свыше тарифа только для определенных вызовов, т.е. сумма всех минут по id не подходит. Необходимо добавить ещё условия "1. только исходящие минуты, 2.только внутри сети"

Задача - выяснить количество минут овер. трафика только в том случае если эти минуты исходящие во внутренней сети.

Comment: @user:519463 Я уже рассматриваю вариант функции, так как нужно выстроить логическую цепь 
`df_revenue_month['direction']=='out') &
df_revenue_month['internal']==True) &
df_revenue_month['tariff_plan']=='A') &
df_revenue_month['total_minutes']>2000))
` 
- тогда делаем то и то.

Comment: 1. Предложенное мной решение подходит. 2. Перед применением этого решения нужно отфильтровать фрейм `df = df[df.direction.eq('out') & df.internal]`. Обновил пример.